# Importing large CSV file to phpMyAdmin

Tags: cmd, phpmyadmin, xampp

Hi guys I want to import a large CSV file to phpMyAdmin. I tried to use XAMPP command prompt:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'the_name_of_mydb.csv'
```

This file contains the database (1048576 members) but I get this error:

[image: CMD]

Please some help to fix this.. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'YOUR_FILE_COMPLETE_PATH' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```